# ERROR: `InResponseTo` does not match any of the possible request IDs (expected [])

Tags: saml-2.0, shibboleth, pingfederate

I'm configuring a PingFederate IdP with a Shibboleth Service Provider. When I click on the `SSO Application Endpoint` in the SP connection of Ping, after entering the username password I get this error message in my SP logs:

ERROR: `InResponseTo` does not match any of the possible request IDs (expected [])

The response does not have an `InResponseTo` attribute. What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the link at the top of the SP connection will start an IdP-initiated SSO transaction. By spec, IdP-initiated responses are considered "unsolicited responses", and cannot contain InResponseTo. You will need to fix your SP so that it requires InResponseTo only when your SP initiates the transaction.

Comment: Thanks! Checked that